# MOODLE - i need a query that returns latest enrolment date in course

Tags: moodle

this query is not returning correct latest_enrolment date. whenever i enrol a user in course, it doesnot updates enrolment date in database.. can anyone help?

```
SELECT  TRIM(c.id) course_id,TRIM(c.fullname) course_fullname,FROM_UNIXTIME(u.timecreated) as registration ,FROM_UNIXTIME( ra.timemodified ) latest_enrolment_date,COUNT( * ) AS enrol_count
                FROM mdl_user u
                INNER JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
                INNER JOIN mdl_context ct ON ct.id = ra.contextid
                INNER JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = ct.instanceid
                INNER JOIN mdl_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid
                INNER JOIN mdl_course_categories cc ON cc.id = c.category
                WHERE r.id =5 GROUP BY c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT MAX(ue.timecreated) AS latest_enrolment_date
FROM mdl_enrol e
JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.enrolid = e.id
WHERE e.courseid = xx
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Russel!!